# Unix: how to get number of days from a given date like 10Dec2022

Tags: date

Team,

Can someone help find code for below..
Unix: how to get a count of number of days from a given date like 10Dec2022 to today.

Looking for Answer: 102 as of (22Mar2023)

Comment: Is it your homeworks? Can you show us the expected output?

Comment: 10Dec2022 at what time? In which timezone? How should it be rounded?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas How is timezone relevant? Has a different number of days passed since 10 Dec 2022 in Tokyo and Washington? Also when asked "how many days till christmas" very few people would answer "281.15423342".

Comment: @Peregrino69, yes, there's 14 hours difference between 2022-12-10T00:00:00 Tokyo time and Washington time. 25 hours difference between Pacific/Midway and Pacific/Kiritimati

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ... Yeah, there is, it's now 21:18 March 21 in Midway, while Kiritimati is 10:18 March 22. But how often is this question interpreted as "How many days have passed in Kiritimati since it was December 22 2022 in Midway"?

Comment: @Peregrino69 In times of trans-continental air traffic ... ;) It all depends on circumstances (which the OP however failed to present so far)

Comment: @AdminBee Right, didn't think of the possibility that the OP's been sitting for months in a plane continuously circulating the Earth eastwards :-D Sometimes questions just are as simple as they seem :-)

Comment: @Peregrino69 :D:D:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's about getting the number of days since that date, with `ddiff` from `dateutils` (sometimes called `dateutils.ddiff`):

```
$ date +%F
2023-03-22
$ dateutils.ddiff -i %d%b%Y 10Dec2022 now
102
```

That's independent of the current time of the day. 0 would be reported from 00:00 to 23:59 local time on 2022-12-10 and increments at midnight.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to fetch the number of days since the start of the year for given date:

##### With `GNU` `date`:

```
$ date -d '10Dec2022' +%j
```

##### With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
$ perl -MTime::Piece -sE '
    say Time::Piece->strptime($date, "%d%b%Y")->strftime("%j")
' -- -date="10Dec2022"
```

##### Output

```
344
```

Comment: Note that `%j` starts at 1 on January 1st 00:00:00, so strictly speaking, it's more like one plus the number of days since the start of the year.